# Why does Ant say "NoClassDefFound" when my JAR is on the classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am using Java 1.6, Eclipse, and Ant.

The following is my target for creating a jar file and running it:

```
    <!-- Settings -->
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>

    <!-- Compile -->
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- Package .jar -->
    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/App.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="main.App" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <!-- Run .jar -->
    <target name="run">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/App.jar" fork="true" />
    </target>
```

The problem is that when I run this jar (via Ant or command-line) I receive the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/xeoh/plugins/base/impl/PluginManagerFactory
     [java]     at plugins.PluginLoader.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Some things that might be useful to know:

- When I print my classpath, it shows that all the requisite JARs are
  there; it also shows up the Eclipse's GUI version of the class path.
- I have tried cleaning the project (both via Eclipse and Ant) to no avail.
- The library .jar that seems to be missing is **not** a .jar in a .jar (which seems to be a common problem).
- This is the only error. Other classes seem to find the library alright...

Comment: The name of the jar is in the classpath, right, and not in a directory, and then the name of the directory is in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, I just double checked. But I believe the `**/*.jar` should handle subdirectories.

Comment: The error you're getting refers to a "plugin" class (and an impl). It might be expecting something such as SPI or and impl jar or such (I'm not familiar with jspf, which it appears to be). At any rate, are you sure that CLASS is IN one of the jars that you know is on the classpath? Do a jar -tvh or otherwise unpack the jar you think it's in and verify.

Comment: The .jar is on the classpath as: `lib/jspf/dist/jspf.core-1.0.2.jar` and it also contains the file `/net/xeoh/plugins/base/impl/PluginManagerFactory.class`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the compile classpath but the App.jar does not include your libs (only the classes you compiled) or a manifest classpath.

You'll need to do the following:

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
    <manifestclasspath property="manifest.classpath"
                       jarfile="${jar.dir}/App.jar">
      <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </manifestclasspath>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/App.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="main.App" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.classpath}" />.
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

See also [ant manifestclasspath task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html)