# Creating runnable Jar files. (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ant, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ant say “NoClassDefFound” when my JAR is on the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387470/why-does-ant-say-noclassdeffound-when-my-jar-is-on-the-classpath)

I currently have 3 java files that I am compiling in Ant. It is using a Java GUI so it depends on 2 .jar files. Compiling using javac and jar works fine in Ant. But once I double click the jar file to run it, it doesn't run. The following errors happen when I try to run it using Java in Ant.

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/layout/GroupLayout$Group
 [java]     at tictactoe.General.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout$Group
```

Etc...

**This is my Ant File**`
    
        Tic Tac Toe - CIS3760A1

```
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="dist/CIS3760A1.jar" basedir="build">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="tictactoe.General"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/org-jdesktop-layout.jar lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build" />
    <delete dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="dist/CIS3760A1.jar" fork="true" classpathref="classpath" />
</target>
```

`

Comment: There is no point in specifying a classpath argument in the 'run' target. When -jar is specified on the command line, the -classpath option is ignored. See the Tool Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Is the JAR file a directory with a lib subdirectory with the 2 required jars?  From the looks of the script, it's building into a dist directory and it doesn't look like it has the required lib directory relative to the main jar.